Devx DataGrid Filter Object Parsing for SQL Query
I would like to post the solution just in case some needs it. The sample code converts the Devx Grid Filters and make a group of object to build the query.



<script>
var t  = [
["city","=","DEMING"],[["city","=","DEMING"],"or",["city","=","BLAIR"]],[[["city","=","DEMING"],"or",["city","=","BLAIR"]],"and",["state","=","NM"]],[[["city","=","DEMING"],"or",["city","=","BLAIR"]],"and",["state","=","NM"],"and",[["zip","=","68023"],"or",["zip","=","68008-0098"]]],
[[["fullName","=","BRIGETTE ROOT"],"or",["fullName","=","CHRISTOPHER COLUMBUS"],"or",["fullName","=","HALEY JOEL OSMENT"]],"and",["!",["city","=","BLAIR"]]]];


function buildflat(o,e)
{
    let flat = o.flat();
    for(let j=0 ; j < flat.length;j++)
    {
        if(Array.isArray(flat[j])) {
           buildflat(flat[j],e);
        } else {
              if(flat[j] === '!') { 
                  flat[j+1][1] =  flat[j] + flat[j+1][1];
             } else {
                e.push(flat[j]);
             }
        }   
    }
}

function buildPairs(e) {
    let pairs = [];
    for(let i=0; i < e.length;i+=4)
    {
        pairs.push([e[i], e[i+1],e[i+2]]);
    }
    return pairs;
}

function groupPairs(p)
{
       let groupmap = {};
       p.map((e) => { 
        if(groupmap[e[0]] === undefined)
         {
            groupmap[e[0]] = [e];
         }
         else {
            groupmap[e[0]].push(e);
         }
       });
    return groupmap;
}

for(let i =0 ; i  < t.length;i++)
{
    let expression = [];
    buildflat(t[i],expression);
    console.log(groupPairs(buildPairs(expression)));
}

</script>



